# How to add and edit Title column for HTML files

Tags: windows-explorer

How can I add a column in Windows Explorer which either will display the title tag from an html document or which I will be able to edit?

For some reason any column that I tried adding including the title column gave me a empty column and couldn't be edited.

Comment: i want to add the title tag from a HTML document and i get a blank column which is useless if i can't edit

Comment: While Windows is indeed capable of editing (among others) MP3 metadata, this is not possible for HTML files.

Comment: i can add any column i want so can i edit mp3 data or that wont work on a html file?

Comment: Like I said: HTML files are not supported.

Comment: what if i changed the file extension to mp3

Comment: It’s still an HTML file even if you rename it. Just give up. It isn’t possible. The end.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Explorer, you can only edit the filename (+ extension). You can't edit any other column. These columns represent different metadata in the file headers and the explorer is not capable of doing what you want. If you tell us what kind of information you want to store, we might be able to suggest an alternative program which can provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: what about the comment column. is that also from the file or is that for adding a comment i.e. i can edit?

Comment: To my knowlegde, the comment column is used for metadata of Microsoft Office files (Word, Excel, etc). You mention in your comments that you want to change HTML-title tags quickly. HTML-Tags are not metadata (on the file system level). Therefore they won't appear as explorer column. If you want to edit those tags quickly, I would suggest you use an editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and use the function Search-Find in files to search for `<title>`. This will give you a list of files with this content which you can edit relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are meant to allow you to sort by a particular file property.  Whether that be the name of the file, the file's size, or the date modified (or many others).  You can't actually edit the names of those columns however as you're basically asking to create a new property for a file which doesn't really make any sense.  For instance, creating a column named walrus and then expecting windows explorer to associate walrus with every file in your windows explorer view is silly.  A file's size makes sense.  A file's walrus, does not.